# Restrictions and Reasoner in Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege4

In my ontology I have a class for Worker which has some properties like first name . 
First name is a functional property , but I want to make sure that it exists in every worker individual.

I added a restriction in the for Worker in the equivalent to part 
`First_Name some string` and just for testing I added another one in subClass of part `First_Name exactly 1 string`

when I add a new individual without a first name , I don't get any error from the reasoner(HermiT).

What is the error or am I misunderstanding something ?

Answer (score 2):

It's the joys of open world reasoning.

person some has_name name

means for every person there is a name. It doesn't mean that you have to know what that name is. So, if you assert a person and do not give them a name, the reasoner will not complain.

If you say

person some has_name (not name)

for example, you would get an error.

Comment: I think this is true with object property but not with data property?